# R: Delete rows based on different values following a certain pattern

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataset and I'd like to delete all the rows which contain the values NA; NA; NA; 0. How can I do that?

```
NAME;   ID;     REFERENCE_YEAR; VALUE
NA;     NA;     NA;             0
ABANO;  767;    1859;           0
ABANO;  767;    1860;           -380
ABANO;  767;    1910;           47
NA;     NA;     NA;             0
ADAMS;  885;    1987;           0
ADAMS;  885;    1988;           -2
ADAMS;  2923;   1997;           NA
ADAMS;  2923;   1999;           NA
ADAMS;  2923;   2000;           NA
ADAMS;  2923;   2002;           NA
ADAMS;  2923;   2007;           NA
ADAMS;  2923;   2008;          -17
NA;     NA;     NA;             0
AEU.PIRCHLKAR;  504;    1981;   0
NA;     NA;     NA;             0
NA;     NA;     NA;             0
```

Comment: What's with the semicolons? Are those an important part of the match? Are you assuming the file is space delimited rather than semi-colon delimited?

Comment: no, its just a normal csv file, semicolons are separating the different columns and the pattern NA, NA, NA, 0 is always the same and these rows should be deleted.

Comment: It looks to me that you are going to delete all the columns based on your stated strategy???? Perhaps you meant to say rows?

Comment: oh man its late I meant rows!!

Comment: Please read your data into R and re-post your data as a data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
  df[!(rowSums(is.na(df[,1:3]))==3 &!df[,4]),]
  #             NAME   ID REFERENCE_YEAR VALUE
  # 2          ABANO  767           1859     0
  # 3          ABANO  767           1860  -380
  # 4          ABANO  767           1910    47
  # 6          ADAMS  885           1987     0
  # 7          ADAMS  885           1988    -2
  # 8          ADAMS 2923           1997    NA
  # 9          ADAMS 2923           1999    NA
  # 10         ADAMS 2923           2000    NA
  # 11         ADAMS 2923           2002    NA
  # 12         ADAMS 2923           2007    NA
  # 13         ADAMS 2923           2008   -17
  # 15 AEU.PIRCHLKAR  504           1981     0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only four columns, calling each column and making logical would not be
a difficult task.

```
index = is.na(data$name) & is.na(data$ID) & is.na(data$REFERENCE_YEAR) & 
(data$VALUE == 0)

data = data[-index, ]
```

If you have more columns, you can use "apply" with custom function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is read using sep=""

```
df[!apply(df,1,paste,collapse="")=="NA;NA;NA;0;",]
```