# How to drop rows by name pattern in R?

Tags: r, regex

My Sample data set have the following look.

```
Country      Population        Capital             Area
A            210000210         Sydney/Landon       10000000
B            420000000         Landon              42100000
C            500000            Italy42/Rome1       9200000   
D            520000100         Dubai/Vienna21A     720000
```

How to delete the entire row with a pattern `/` in its column. I have tried to look in the following link [R: Delete rows based on different values following a certain pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171750/r-delete-rows-based-on-different-values-following-a-certain-pattern), but it does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `grepl`

```
df[!grepl('[/]', df$Capital),]
#   Country Population Capital     Area
#2       B  420000000  Landon 42100000
```

Comment: Thanks... will it work for more than one `///` also.

Comment: @AaghazHussain, just give it a try: `grepl('[/]', c("Sydney/Landon", "Sydney///Landon", "///Sydney/Landon"))`

Comment: @ docendo, my data entries with `/`, `//`,`///` may be more than 4000, is not it difficult to do it by `c("Sydney/Landon", "Sydney///Landon", "///Sydney/Landon"))`

Comment: The answer by akrun will match any string with at least 1 `/`, also if there are multiple `/`, as in my comment above (just run those lines and see what is returned).

Comment: @ docendo discimus.. Your above code returns `TRUE TRUE TRUE`.

Comment: @AaghazHussain, correct. Because each string in that example hast at least one / in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(Capital, "\\/"))
#   Country Population Capital     Area
# 1       B  420000000  Landon 42100000
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Country = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Population = c(210000210L,420000000L, 500000L, 520000100L), 
                     Capital = c("Sydney/Landon", "Landon", "Italy42/Rome1", "Dubai/Vienna21A"), 
                     Area = c(10000000L, 42100000L, 9200000L, 720000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L))
```